# How to differentiate between insert and update in transformation

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

I have this table in database that has these columns

**student**

```
student_id INT

student_name VARCHAR

class_name VARCHAR
```

I want to transform the table to two tables

**student_transformed**

```
student_key 

student_id 

student_name
```

**class transformed**

```
class_key       

class_name
```

My problem is transformation on class table:

To insert new records:

```
select * 
  from student  s
  left
  join class_transformed  c
    on s.class_name = c.class_name
```

But if the class_name get updated in student tables, it would be a new row record. In other words it is not possible to differentiate between insert and update.

My question is, how to do the transformation and make insert and update work? please note that we don't have class_id.

Comment: How familiar are you with slowly changing dimensions?

Comment: @Error_2646, I am familiar with scd, the problem here is that I don't have IDs for the class and the name can change so it causes problems in update and insert.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Sorry - there is no way to do what you want with just the data you've provided. There simply isn't sufficient information. If this is a real-world problem you need to go upstream in the dataflow and get some persistent class identifier. Maybe if a class name could change but you'd expect all the students associated with the class to stay the same you could do some ugly overwrite, but that is far-fetched.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need another table like :

Student_to_Class

```
Student_key

Class_key
```

then this will work

```
select * 
  from student  s
left join Student_to_Class s2c
on s.student_key = s2c.student_key
  left join class_transformed  c
    on s2c.class_key= c.class_key
```

Comment: I think the problem is more tricky than a junction table can solve. It's difficult to tell without know the exact nature of the data, but from what he's describing it sounds like the problem is like this - imagine you want to load a "Person" table. In a perfect world you'd have {id, name} such that Day1: {1, Jane Doe} is an insert Day2: {2, John Deer} is an insert Day3 {1, Jane Deer} (they got married) is an update. Without the id it's impossible to know if Jane Deer is a new person, or an existing person whose name changed. I'm assuming that this is critical for his data.